# Standard name for the computation of Lagrange multipliers iteratively by fixing other multipliers?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Dear Optimization Experts,

**Background**:

I have a convex optimization problem on hand that can be shown in general form as given below
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^N}{\text{minimize}} 
& & f(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & g_i(x) -  \alpha_i \leq 0 \ \ \forall i = 1,\cdots,K \; ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where both functions $g_i: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are convex, and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is given.

The Lagrangian is:
\begin{align}
L\left(x, \left\{\lambda_i\right\}\right) 
&= f(x) + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{K} \lambda_i \left(g_i(x) -  \alpha_i \right) \; .
\end{align}

**Question**:

If $K=1$ then I can obtain the closed-form solution $x$ (and analytical solution of the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_1$) by following the KKT conditions.

Now, the *question arises* when $K > 1$ then I can't obtain the closed-form solution, but I can compute $x$ analytically which is dependent on all the  $\lambda_i$. So, to compute the Lagrange multiplier say $\lambda_i$, I resort to iterative solution where I fix other Lagrange multipliers ($\lambda_j \ \forall j = 1,\cdots,K$ except $i$). Then repeat the above process for other Lagrange multipliers iteratively.

- do you have any standard name for such scheme to compute Lagrange multipliers cyclically?
- If not, can I say that this cyclic/iterative scheme  is nothing but Coordinate Descent (or like)?

Thank you so much for your time in advance.

Comment: Depending on how you select $\lambda$, this may be coordinate descent in the dual problem.

Comment: thank you LinAlg!